# Cluster configuration problems in cassandra.yaml for multi-node cluster where only 1 public ip is known

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I would like to know about configuration parameters of cassandra.yaml namely,

1. listen_address
2. broadcast_address
3. rpc_address
4. broadcast_rpc_address

on individual nodes in a particular scenario.

**Scenario**: 6-node cluster with respective private IPs but only one node has a public IP.

*Requirement:* remote python application to access the cluster

**What I have tried on each node:**

1. listen_address: respective `private IP`
2. broadcast_address: `blank`
3. rpc_address: `blank` 
   *except* on node with public ip as `0.0.0.0`
4. broadcast_rpc_address: `blank` *except* on node with public ip as its `public ip`

I tried issuing from my application Cluster(['`public ip`'], port=9042) but I received the warning which eventually led to shutting down my application:

> WARNING:cassandra.cluster:Failed to create connection pool for new
>   host 192.xxx.xx.3:

Answer (score 0):

I recommend adding two interfaces to each machine.

One of them is `listen_address` 
and one for the `rpc_address`. 
in this approach, you don't use as `broadcast_rpc_address`.

but, if you use for public ip  you have to put a general address for all nodes. Only one of them can not have a public address.